# mysql insert from select ran out of memory?

Tags: mysql, memory

I am trying to insert into a table (A) by selecting data from a different table (B). I wrote the query, it is working fine, but the size of table B is too large. So the query seems to be breaking after inserting 23k rows.

Can some one suggest me is there any way to solve with mysql configuration. I know one way would be to break the insert query with where condition, but if i'll be able to solve it with configuring mysql, my life will be a lot easier.

Comment: How does INSERT query look like?

Comment: its like, -----insert into A (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 from B,C where B.cId = C.id group by B.col1

Answer (score 0):

Edit the my.cnf file for MySQL and increase the sort_buffer_size

Not sure what you should set it to for your request but you can experiment a bit.

If this doesn't work out you could try increasing other buffer sizes as well but you should back up the my.cnf file before doing this.